# Scroll to bottom on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firebase

I have the following code, it's a chat display that I got using the Firebase API. 
The problem is that, when the page loads, I want it to directly have the scrollbar set at the bottom. At the moment it is sort of sliding slowly to the bottom (because of the .animate).
How can I have the scrollbar always stay at the bottom when I reload the page, even if new content is added to the chat?

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://ot7fwnsj7h7.firebaseio-demo.com/');
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
    });

    function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
        $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name + ': ')).appendTo($('#displayChat'));
        // make text scroll everytime someone posts
        $('#displayChat').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#displayChat")[0].scrollHeight
        }, 'slow');
    };
});
```

And here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qxkr35pj/

I hope I've been clear! Thanks.

Comment: How about adding `$('#displayChat').scrollTop(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code scrolls the element to its bottom.
Call it every time you update the view.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxkr35pj/3)

```
$("#displayChat")[0].scrollTop =  $("#displayChat")[0].scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this instead of your animate code:

`$('#displayChat').scrollTop($("#displayChat").height());`

You'd also want to use that every time a message gets added - it'll take the scrollbar to the bottom of the div.